# How can I specify the htaccess to match all files except index.html?

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following code for authentication where if the url is is not index.html, display the authenticatio form

```
<files "(?!index.html)">
    AuthUserFile  C:/wamp/www/eyedream/trunk/www/.htpasswd
    AuthName "Please login"
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
</files>
```

How can I specify if the file is not index.html,display the authentication box?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Auth directives inside a `<Files>` block, it's got to be inside a `<Directory>` or in an .htaccess file. You can set an environment variable and use `Satisfy Any` to bypass the authentication for certain requests though:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/index.html$ norequire_auth=true
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/$ norequire_auth=true

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile C:/wamp/www/eyedream/trunk/www/.htpasswd
AuthName "Please login"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=norequire_auth
```